# How to organize python test in a way that I can run all tests in a single command?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-nose

Currently my code is organized in the following tree structure:

```
src/
    module1.py
    module2.py
    test_module1.py
    test_module2.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
        test_moduleA.py
        test_moduleB.py
```

Where the `module*.py` files contains the source code and the `test_module*.py` contains the `TestCase`s for the relevant module.

With the following comands I can run the tests contained in a single file, for example:

```
$ cd src
$ nosetests test_filesystem.py
..................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 18 tests in 0.390s

OK
```

How can I run all tests? I tried with `nosetests -m 'test_.*'` but it doesn't work.

```
$cd src
$ nosetests -m 'test_.*'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they all begin with `test` then just `nosetest` should work.  Nose automatically searches for any files beginning with 'test'.

Comment: I found the problem, nosetests skip they because are executables.
I fixed resetting the executable permission bit and removing svn:executable property from subversion property.

Comment: The [--exe](http://packages.python.org/nose/usage.html#cmdoption--exe) option will prevent nosetests from skipping executable files.

Comment: It is probably worth considering the move to `nose2` instead of `nosetest`.
https://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 16):

Whether you seperate or mix tests and modules is probably a matter of taste, although I would strongly advocate for keeping them apart (setup reasons, code stats etc).

When you're using nosetests, make sure that all directories with tests are real packages:

```
src/
    module1.py
    module2.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_module1.py
    test_module2.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        test_moduleA.py
        test_moduleB.py
```

This way, you can just run `nosetests` in the toplevel directory and all tests will be found. You need to make sure that `src/` is on the `PYTHONPATH`, however, otherwise all the tests will fail due to missing imports.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about nosetests, but you can achieve that with the standard unittest module. You just need to create a `test_all.py` file under your root directory, then import all your test modules. In your case:

```
import unittest
import test_module1
import test_module2
import subpackage1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    allsuites = unittest.TestSuite([test_module1.suite(), \
                                test_module2.suite(), \
                                subpackage1.test_moduleA.suite(), \
                                subpackage1.test_moduleB.suite()])
```

each module should provide the following function (example with a module with two unit tests: `Class1` and `Class2`):

```
def suite():
    """ This defines all the tests of a module"""
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Class1))
    suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Class2))
    return suite
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, except that I think you should omit the `()` after each suite name (at least under Python 2.6.5).

Comment: Python 2.7 has a way to automatically find test modules/packages, which seems easier to maintain than remembering to add them explicitly to a test_all.py. See http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a hotly-contested topic, but I would suggest that you separate your tests out from your modules.  Set up something like this...

Use `setup.py` to install these into the system path (or you may be able to modify environment variables to avoid the need for an "install" step).

```
foo/
    module1.py
    module2.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
```

Now any python script anywhere can access those modules, instead of depending on finding them in the local directory.  Put your tests all off to the side like this:

```
tests/
    test_module1.py
    test_module2.py
    test_subpackage1_moduleA,py
    test_subpackage2_moduleB.py
```

I'm not sure about your `nosetests` command, but now that your tests are all in the same directory, it becomes much easier to write a wrapper script that simply imports all of the other tests in the same directory.  Or if that's not possible, you can at least get away with a simple `bash` loop that gets your test files one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd tests/
for TEST_SCRIPT in test_*.py ; do
    nosetests -m $TEST_SCRIPT
done
```

Comment: I'd suggest to reflect the package structure of the program in the test directory. Otherwise the test directory will become a mess when the program grows.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a [Testoob](http://www.testoob.org) answer.

Running tests in a single file is like Nose:

```
testoob test_foo.py
```

To run tests in many files you can create suites with the Testoob collectors (in each subpackage)

```
# src/subpackage?/__init__.py
def suite():
  import testoob
  return testoob.collecting.collect_from_files("test_*.py")
```

and

```
# src/alltests.py
test_modules = [
    'subpackage1.suite',
    'subpackage2.suite',
]

def suite():
    import unittest
    return unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(test_modules)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import testoob
    testoob.main(defaultTest="suite")
```

I haven't tried your specific scenario.